# Basic time intervals are inconsistent here

Tags: python, timer, clock, alarm, stopwatch

Simple question: Why are the intervals inconsistent?

(This is just a basic test to indicate 3.000 second intervals, yet running on the cmd prompt shows variations between 3.001 to 3.020. On a 2.2 ghz processor, this delay seems unreasonable. What am I missing?)

```
import time
import random
from graphics import *

def main():

    print("Press Enter to start & CTRL+C to exit.")  

    while True:
        try:
            start=time.time()
            time.sleep(3.000)
            interval=time.time()
            print("Total time:", round(abs(interval-start),3),"second interval")
            
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKfDa.png)

Comment: The inaccuracies are explained in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep

Comment: Your script isn't the only thing running on your computer or even within the Python interpreter, so an approximation is all that's possible.